# Iterate on an EF objects to see only "new values" before saving changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm adding new objects in any EF object.
Just before to saves the changes from EF to the database, i would like to iterate on my object in order see all the value i add.

If i made a simple:

```
var Categories = myDb.category;
foreach (var category in Categories)
{
    .....
}
```

It will give me "all" the values no ? Values i add, and, values already in the database.

How can I get all the values "in standby" to be "saved in database" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var Categories = myDb.ChangeTracker.Entries<Category>()
                     .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);    

foreach (var category in Categories)
{
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: If necessary I would extend it by status Modified to have updated values too. For me updated values are new values in database. Nevertheless it is a possible solution.

Comment: And you should add `.Select(e => e.Entity)`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try. If it's not good, i think i should use a simple List<T>.

Comment: @GertArnold Why     .Select(e => e.Entity) and where add it?

Comment: It's perfect guys :) Thanks a lot !